# Polynomial regression with periodicity constraints. Can we find an optimal basis?

Tags: polynomials, soft-question, fourier-analysis, periodic-functions, linear-regression

Imagine we want to do linear least squares fit on some interval $t\in[0,1]$, 
$$\min_{\bf v}\{\|{\bf \Phi v -d} \|_2^2\}$$
for a polynomial $t\to p(t)$ :

$$p(t) = \sum_{k=0}^M {\bf v}_k t^k$$

but with additional constraints:

$$p^{(k)}(0)=p^{(k)}(1) \hspace{1cm} \forall k \in \{ 0,\cdots,N \}$$

In other words no "jumps" in derivative for function or it's $N$ first derivatives.

Assuming degree of polynomial is $M$, which values of $N$ would be possible?

How restrictive would this be for our polynomial?

Given $M$ and $N$, can we find a "best basis" in some sense to represent this polynomial?

---

I assume in the extreme case that as $N$ goes to infinity, $M$ will necessarily need to grow to infinity as well and only degrees of freedom left would be equivalent to power series expansions for the basis function of Fourier series expansion on this interval.

Comment: Each derivative condition represents a single constraint on the coefficients of $p$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I also thought so, but I don't know how it will translate into choosing some particular polynomial basis.

Comment: Each condition decreases the dimension of the set of allowed polynomials by one.  Then, find a basis of the remaining polynomials using standard linear algebra.